# Unable to make AndEngine game to Full-Screen

Tags: android, andengine

I just started to learn AndEngine and find myself having trouble will full-Screen. I've set the basic setup so that the app will run with full screen , however, only the  black navigation bar below the app shows up. I tried many ways but cannot hide the bar. My current app min is 13 and supports all the way up to lolipop. I posted the part of the  manifest below. I really need some help ! I would love to hear from you!

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you specified true as first parameter when creating the engine options in

```
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions()
```

?

Sample code (adapt for your resolution and resolution policy):

```
@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    this.camera = new Camera(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR,
    new RatioResolutionPolicy(16, 9), this.camera);
}
```